# Heroku push incomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a rails app that works perfectly in localhost, but last time I pushed it to Heroku the "About" and "Contact" sections seems like incomplete upload or something, here is the link to the website https://damp-inlet-9409.herokuapp.com, and yes, I re-pushed like 3 times and still the same result

Update:

I think the problem is from development.rb or production.rb, here you got them:

Production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

Comment: You should really add a lot more description to your question - at the moment, it's very broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several potentialities with your issue.

Firstly, you're getting a *rails* error, which means that at the base level (IE Heroku database etc), the app should be working okay.

The main problem for many `Heroku` apps is that they either don't have a database, which would yield the Heroku "Application Error":

[image]

For future reference, this error means that you have an issue with how *Heroku* is running your app (typically that you don't have a db or something).

Since you have a *rails* error, it means that the problem is likely an undeclared variable, or missing conditional login etc.

--

To fix the issue, you need to check the `Heroku` logs:

[image]

This will give you a specific readout of the problem that's preventing the app from running. You'll then either be better placed to give us the details of said error, or fix the problem yourself.

Comment: It worked! I just needed a rake db:migrate from Heroku, but the image in "About" still looks kinda incomplete, any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Try `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` in your local env, then push to Heroku again ;) If it worked, you should mark the answer as correct so that others don't get confused

Comment: Didn't work :( I updated the post so it may help you, thanks Rich btw

Comment: Okay, when you say it didn't work, how can you tell? It looks okay to me. Can you be specific on what the problem is?

Comment: In the "About" section, don't you see the image like incomplete? Like it didn't completely charge, or it's just me?

Comment: Ok, it just happens in my computer I don't know why, I'm sorry. Thank you very much for your help Rich!

Comment: Try resetting the cache on your system ;)